# How to convert date from form for MySql

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a fairly simple question - I have a form where users enter their date of birth in `dd/mm/yyyy` format, which is stored as `0000-00-00` in my database. I am sure this is a simple task to rectify, could someone help me write the code that converts the input date format into a format the database understands? Thanks!

```
$date_of_birth = $_POST['date_birth']; .................
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", $_POST['date_birth']);
$date_of_birth = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/CK3H53)

Comment: Does that work with euro-style dd/mm/yyyy which is what the OP is looking for?

Comment: I just wanted to say "euro-style". I even said it out loud when I typed it. Both times.

Comment: Ok, I'm a total noob when it comes to php so I apologise for seeming simple! If I'm correct, echo is used to print the data on the display (or perhaps I'm wrong - more likely!), but with regards to the line of code I currently have to send the data from the form to the database, how would I use your code to do this? Many thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I updated my answer to use the POST variable you'll be using and to put the date of birth into a variable. Now you can use that variable in your query.

Comment: Hmm, I spoke to soon - I get this error after form submit: Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::createFromFormat()

I am using a spry text field set up to validate date entry format on the form, could this be interfering?

Comment: what version of php are you using? `DateTime::createFromFormat` is only available as of `5.3.0`

Comment: In phpMyAdmin I appear to be using V3.3.3 ... 123-reg.co.uk host my site so that's what is available to me

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Apologies I wasn't sure how to figure it out but I've got it now - PHP Version 5.2.17

Answer (score 1):

mysql has date formatting built in, see DATE_FORMAT and STR_TO_DATE https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

```
$date_of_birth = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['date_birth']));
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have any effect - I am using a spry text field (for form validation), would this cause an issue with this code?

Comment: when your form is submit then you can convert before saving in database

Comment: I've implemented the code from the first response to my question but many thanks for your help!